# Switch case with gcd

Tags: objective-c, xcode, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to load my arrays using SWITCH and GCD in order not to stop main thread. But Xcode cannt build my code. Please can anyone explain me why I could use GCD in this way?

```
switch (number) {
        case 0:
            //case 0:exercise_name="Стойка";
            break;

        case 1:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                @synchronized (self.handsMassage){
                    /*
                     NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
                     _click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
                     self.click.delegate = self;
                     */
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 22; i++) {
                        [self.arrayOfExercise addObject:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ml_%i", i]].CGImage];
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.playButton setHidden:NO];
                });
            });
            break;

        case 2:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                @synchronized (self.loinMassage){
                    /*
                     NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
                     _click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
                     self.click.delegate = self;
                     */
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                        [self.arrayOfExercise addObject:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mp_%i", i]].CGImage];
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.playButton setHidden:NO];
                });
            });
            break;
```

XCode print me switch case in protected mode?

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto
[img](http://s013.radikal.ru/i324/1412/8f/3d17570140d0.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `{` and `}` around each case. Like this:

```
switch (number) {
        case 0:
        {
            //case 0:exercise_name="Стойка";
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                @synchronized (self.handsMassage){
                    /*
                     NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
                     _click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
                     self.click.delegate = self;
                     */
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 22; i++) {
                        [self.arrayOfExercise addObject:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ml_%i", i]].CGImage];
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.playButton setHidden:NO];
                });
            });
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                @synchronized (self.loinMassage){
                    /*
                     NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"]];
                     _click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
                     self.click.delegate = self;
                     */
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                        [self.arrayOfExercise addObject:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mp_%i", i]].CGImage];
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.playButton setHidden:NO];
                });
            });
            break;
        }
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Yes)Thanks)But why it was so?

Comment: Because like if statements you can only put a single statement after a case. You should defensively always put brackets after conditionals.  You'll avoid bugs and make code clear. With the length of that code you should factor it out to another method.

Comment: uchuugaka's comment is incorrect.  You are not limited to a single statement after a case: label.  The case labels indicate where execution should start, and execution continues until the end of the switch statement (or until break is encountered).  You can't place declarations after the case label.